# combineReducers breaks simple unit tests ? Initial state behavior is changed

Tags: redux, react-redux

New to React-redux, using React (from create-react-app) with react-redux and Jest for tests

The main problem is the difference in behavior when using combineReducers ater refactoring a big reducer and chopping it into small individual reducers

So, I am testing my initial state with a simple `expect(store.getState()).toEqual({});`
When using a single 'big' reducer, the tests passes since the single reducers returns {} by default

But when I am combining the new reducers, I get the slice of the state each reducer is responsible of into my state. This is breaking the test and show that the app will behave differently

So, with :
 `createStore(combineReducers({users: receiveUsersReducer, questions: receiveQuestionsReducer, userLoggedIn: userLoggedIn})` and with each reducer having its default state parameter set to `(state = {}, action = {})`

I get the following result :

```
    - Expected
    + Received

   - Object {}
    + Object {
    +   "questions": Object {},
    +   "userLoggedIn": Object {},
    +   "users": Object {},
    + }
```

empty objects for each reducers where I would wait a for simple {}

It means that I will have to add an extra "key" layer (with questions, users or userLoggedI) when accessing my state over the App now ? For example, if I had :

```
const currentState = store.getState()
currenState.users
```

will i now need :

```
const currentState = store.getState().users
currenState.users
```

Thank you for clarification

Comment: What was the structure of your store state, when you had it in a big single reducer?

Comment: The structure of the state was the same.The difference is that now, in each individual reducer, i need to return parts of state they are responsible for whereas before, I had to manually add the key for the slice of the state i was managing.

Before combineReducers: 
`switch (action.type) {

        case LOG_IN:
            return {...state, userLoggedIn: action.userLoggedIn};`

After combine reducers : 
`case LOG_IN:
            return action.userLoggedIn;`

(Sorry dunno how to format that)

Comment: That is the correct behavior and should work this way. However, if store.getState().users.users doesnt sounds good ,you can just change your reducers name i.e users => usersReducer and access the state as store.getState().usersReducer.users

Comment: And usually we dont name the state with the reducer name, we use state keyword as a key i.e. const usersState = store.getState().users.state

Comment: Ok, it's a little odd for me to have to change the state (the logic) of the app, just because combining the reducers...Thank you for the help @MuhammadHaseeb